# Update table column after insert into same table-PLSQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

There are 4 columns in a table, marks1, marks2,marks3 and total.
The trigger should calculate the total and update the total when we insert marks1, marks2 and marks3.

Answer (score 2):

If it happens that you are using Oracle 11g, to achieve the desired result you can add a virtual column to a table:

```
SQL> create table your_table(
  2    marks1 number,
  3    marks2 number,
  4    marks3 number
  5  )
  6  ;

Table created

SQL> 
SQL> alter table your_table
  2    add total number generated always as (nvl(marks1, 0)+
  3                                          nvl(marks2, 0)+
  4                                          nvl(marks3, 0)
  5                                          )
  6  ;

Table altered

SQL> insert into your_table(marks1,marks2,marks3)
  2    values(1,2,3);

1 row inserted

SQL> commit;

Commit complete

SQL> select * from your_table;

    MARKS1     MARKS2     MARKS3      TOTAL
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1          2          3          6
```

Comment: Only (clean) way to go actually. Or below 11G using a view which can do the same

Answer (score 1):

```
create or replace trigger calc_total
before insert on your_table
for each row
begin
  :new.total := :new.marks1 + :new.marks2 + :new.marks3;
end;
```